# Trying to publish an azure function via dotnet publish command

Tags: .net, azure, function, publish

We are facing an issue while trying to deploy a function app via the dotnet publish command line. All other apps publish successfully. The only difference is that this is a function app while the others are app services.

This is the pubxml:

[image: PUBXML]

This is the command:

[image: Command]

and this is the outcome:

[image: Outcome]

It seems it builds the project but never uploads it.

Any help please?

Answer (score -2):

Thank you [Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/187100/andy) posting your [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53048008/the-dotnet-publish-command-line-skips-deployment-to-azure-functions?rq=1) as an answer to help other community members.

"I have an MSBuild command line that is working to deploy my .NET Core 2.1 Function project:

```cs
msbuild /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:PublishProfile=somename.pubxml /p:Configuration=Release
```

It is, however, worth noting the following:

*General .NET Core publishing notes*

1. If you miss-spell the publish profile name, it will silently skip deployment (no warning or error).

*Differences between ASP. NET Core and .NET Core Functions deployment*

2. If you use 'dotnet publish', it will always skip deployment.
3. If you don't specify /p:DeployOnBuild=True, it'll skip deployment."

Please refer the below link for more information:
MS DOC:  [Create a C# function in Azure from the command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-cli-csharp?tabs=in-process,azure-cli&pivots=programming-runtime-functions-v3)

Comment: I'm getting "No
 se especificó un valor para la tarea "ZipDeployTask" para el parámetro "DeploymentPassword" requerido."